# How to change this to HTML from PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

i want to change this into html format

> echo " http://somedomain/somepath/usn_handler.php?usn='" . $row['usn'] .
>        "' >" . $row['usn'] . " ";

Comment: How do you mean from `PHP` to `HTML`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You need to show some attempt at solving the problem or research of your own.

Comment: I've doing Mysql, and ive returned a table. I now need to create a link in the table that goes onto another page showing more information about that record

Comment: Basically i have this line
> out.println("<td>" + rs1.getString("title") + "</td>");

and i need it so i can make the result a hyperlink that queries something else

Comment: BAHAHAH, dude, are you writing Java or PHP? see edits: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26985419/revisions

Comment: This is javascript, not PHP.

Comment: It's Java, not JavaScript, but it did used to be PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work

```
?>
<a href="http://somedomain/somepath/usn_handler.php?usn=<?php echo $row['usn']; ?>">link</a>
<?php
```

If you are just making a link to the same domain omit the full URL

```
?>
<a href="somepath/usn_handler.php?usn=<?php echo $row['usn']; ?>">link</a>
<?php
```

Assuming you want to make a hyper link. But really you should just google first.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean something like this :

```
<div>
http://somedomain/somepath/usn_handler.php?usn=<?php echo $row['usn']; ?>' >" <?php echo $row['usn']; ?> 
</div>
```

or :

```
  <div>
    <a src="http://somedomain/somepath/usn_handler.php?usn=<?php echo $row['usn']; ?>" > <?php echo $row['usn']; ?></a> 
    </div>
```